# set tempdata in from Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can i **set** tempdata in from Global.asax?

asp.net-mvc-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, object> tempDataDictionary = Context.Session["__ControllerTempData"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
                if (tempDataDictionary == null)
                {
                    tempDataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                }
                **tempDataDictionary["TopMessage"] = message;
                tempDataDictionary["FromUnauthorized"] = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Session["__ControllerTempData"] = tempDataDictionary;**
                Server.ClearError();
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/LogOn");
```

Comment: There you go.  But WTF are you trying to do?!